# Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, keras

I changed the data type but I could not resolve the error.

I tried One-Hot Encoding but it doesn't work too.

I don't know what's wrong:(

```
seed = 0
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.set_random_seed(seed)

df = pd.read_csv('HW01_dataset_tae.txt', sep=',' ,header=None, names = ["Native", "Instructor", "Course", "Semester", "Class Size", "Evaluation"])

dataset = df.values # dataframe to int64
X = dataset[:,0:5] # attribute
Y_Eva = dataset[:,5] # class 

e = LabelEncoder()
e.fit(Y_Eva)
Y = e.transform(Y_Eva)

K = 10 
kFold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=K, shuffle=True, random_state=seed) 

accuracy = []

for train_index, test_index in kFold.split(X,Y):
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=5, activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X[train_index], Y[train_index], epochs=100, batch_size=2)
```

the error ; Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

is detected at here ; model.fit(X[train_index], Y[train_index], epochs=100, batch_size=2).

What shout I do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

At this code,

```
model.fit(X[train_index], Y[train_index], epochs=100, batch_size=2)
```

the number of rows in 'Y[train_index]' must be three because the classes are three.

The error came out since each Y[train_index] has only one row.

So, I used One-Hot Encoding and changed the code like this.

```
e = LabelEncoder()
e.fit(Y_Eva)
Y = e.transform(Y_Eva)
Y_encoded = np_utils.to_categorical(Y) # changed code

K = 10 
kFold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=K, shuffle=True, random_state=seed) 

accuracy = []

for train_index, test_index in kFold.split(X,Y):
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=5, activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X[train_index], Y_encoded[train_index], epochs=100, batch_size=2) # changed code
```

Finally, I was able to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow has made some documenation on the dense layer, and if you then instead of saying input_dim says input_shape you can specify the prefered shape.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(5,)))  # Then your data has to be of shape (batch x 5)
```

When you then are adding another dense layer, you actaully don't have to provide the input_sahpe

```
model.add(Dense(10))
```

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you. I changed input data type not input_shape or input_dim. 
Anyway it didn't work

Comment: But you input shape is just 5 or [batch_size, 5]?

Comment: just 5. batch size is 2 and epoch is 100

Comment: Then you need to change the input shape to [batch_size, 5]

Comment: I solved the problem in a different way. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Nice, how'd you solve it? Maybe answer your own question so other people can see the answer